# C# Winform Application

Tags: c#, database-connection

I am creating a winform application which connects to a ms-access database. The problem is with my connection string as i can access the database locally but if i run from my usb stick or from any other pc it would give me error. How can i modify my connection string so that i can run my application on other pc without any trouble.

```
string strConnect = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Aakash\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Industrial Foundry\record.accdb";
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConnect))
{
    con.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from Industry ", con))
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your connection string contains a hard coded path to the database on your C: drive. How do you want to locate the access file?

Comment: What does this have to do with WinForms? Please revise your tags, and also, replace your question title. Currently, your question title comprises of the language (irrelevant, given in the tags), a UI toolkit (entirely irrelevant to the question, as far as I can tell) and a very general word (*application*) that does not say anything about the problem you are facing.

Comment: 2 immediate issues; 

1. Your database connection string contains a file system path; this path must exist on every machine you use the app on.

2. If you are using Access and the target machine does not have access installed, you'll need to install the runtime distributable from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: I would compile the project and would give the release version of files to my client to run on his PC.

Comment: @dash The target machine has access installed but the issue here is the data source as i dont know how can it be changed from pc to pc.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string points directly to a path on your C: drive.

There are a number of ways that you could fix it; you could just prompt the user for the file location, and/or store it in a user configurable settings file.

Comment: How do i store the path in a user configurable ini file??? Could you please provide me some code which would help me with the start.

Comment: I would suggest using `System.XML`. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7718/Using-XML-in-C-in-the-simplest-way

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

Create a *winform* where you can input parameters like "server", "password", etc., etc
After that, update your connection string with the parameters:

```
Friend Principal As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("data source=" & My.Settings.Server & ";INITIAL CATALOG=" & My.Settings.DB & ";UID=" & My.Settings.User & ";PWD=" & My.Settings.Password & ";workstation id=" & My.Settings.PC & ";packet size=4096")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be a good start:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Since your title indicates you have a WinForms application, you may also want to consider adding a "Browse" button to locate the database and then using a [connection string builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254947%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to build your connection.

Comment: Is there any other alternative apart from creating a browse button and manually finding the database each time user opens the form. i want to make a simple application when he opens the form click on a button records are displayed from database. But the trouble is data source as it is fixed for my pc's path.

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking if there is some way to "guess" the data source path - obviously you will need to ask for it at least once.  But it is easy to persist the path to the [user settings file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think simple way for you would be use App.Config file (Application Configuration File), you can add your database key in config file, when app launch you can check if key value is null than you should force user to choose database path, and you can set that database path to your config file. You can read your key value something using..

**Code for Read Key**

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DBKey"];
```

**Code for Write Key**

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AppSettingsSection app = config.AppSettings;
app.Settings.Add("DBKey", "DBPath");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified)
```

Thanks
Suresh